# Perl Mason2 passing arrays and hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, dancer, mason

I'm trying to use Mason2 with Dancer and trivial cases like passing string to the template are working fine:

```
get '/foo', sub {
    template 'foo' => {
        title => 'bar'
    };
  };
    <%args>
    $.title
    </%args>
    <h1><% $.title %></h1>
```

So, this is working. Troubles started when I wanted to pass things like hashes or arrays to the template.
And when I pass this array to the template:

```
template 'index', {  cats=> [{id=>1,title=>'Cat1'},{id=>2,title=>'Cat2'}]};
```

And set args in the template to

```
<%args>
$.cats
</%args>
```

I cannot loop through this array like this:

```
<ul>
% foreach my $cat ($.cats){
<li><% $cat %></li>
% } 
</ul>
```

$cat object is the same as $.cats object, an array.
I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mason, but I'm pretty sure that `% foreach my $cat ( @{$.cats} ) {` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) is exactly right. `$.cats` is an array reference; to loop through the elements, you have to dereference it:

```
<%args>
$.cats
</%args>

<ul>
% foreach my $cat ( @{$.cats} ) {
  <li><% $cat->{title} %></li>
% }
</ul>
```

Output:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Cat1</li>
  <li>Cat2</li>
</ul>
```

Note that `<% $cat %>` evaluates `$cat` in scalar context and outputs it; since `$cat` is a hash reference, this will output something like `HASH(0x4b9fad8)`. To output items from the hash, you have to access them by key, e.g. `<% $cat->{id} %>`.

Comment: Thank you Borodin and ThisSuitIsBlackNot. That was it